# Could not find driver will be seen on command prompt

Tags: php, windows, doctrine

I am implementing doctrin2 with zend framework2 .when i am executing a command

```
./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Album\\Entity\\" --force  --from-database annotation ./module/Album/src/
```

then i have seen an error `[PDOException] could not find driver` .
My code is given below

My doctrine.local.php

```
<?php
    return array(
        'doctrine' => array(
            'connection' => array(
                'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver',
                     'params' => array(
                          'user' => 'root',
                          'password' => '',
                ),
            ),
        )
));

?>
my doctrine.global.php
    <?php

    return array(
        'doctrine' => array(
            'connection' => array(
                'orm_default' => array(
                    'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                        'params' => array(
                            'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
                            'host' => 'localhost',
                            'dbname' => 'test',
                    ),
                ),
            )
    ));

    ?>

my application.module.config.php

    'modules' => array(
            'Application',
            'DoctrineModule',
            'DoctrineORMModule',
             'Album',
        ),
In my album/module.config.php i have also add this code

    namespace Album;

    'doctrine' => array(
            'driver' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                    'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                    'cache' => 'array',
                    'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
                ),
                'orm_default' => array(
                    'drivers' => array(
                        __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

- There is a missing `driver` key in your `params` array.
- Did you enabled the specific driver extensions such as `php_pdo_mysql`, `php_pdo_pgsql` in your PHP config?

Comment: I have already use driver key like 'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql', in doctrine.global.php. and both extensions( php_pdo_mysql, php_pdo_pgsql) are activated in my php config. I am using mysql so i think i should activate only one which is "php_pdo_mysql". Thanks for suggations.

Answer (score 0):

open `./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module`

and change

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env php5
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this might be necessary? Please [edit] your answer to include a description.